# Pinnable taskpanes are currently only supported by Outlook 2016 for Windows

Tags: office-js

[Pinnable taskpanes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane) are currently only supported by Outlook 2016 for Windows, is Microsoft going to support in Mac and older version of Outlook (2013) in next release?

Answer (score 0):

Pinnable taskpane would be coming to MAC in another 2 months.

Comment: Currently, we do not have any plans to add support for Pinnable Taskpanes to older versions of Outlook (for Windows).

Comment: Thanks for your response.